# Kotlin/Ktorm java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: java.sql.SQLException

Tags: java, kotlin, noclassdeffounderror

I'm working on a project using Kotlin compose for desktop and Ktorm.
Running it directly within IntelliJ works but trying to run the distributable (after creating it via gradle tasks) gives me this error:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class DatabaseKt
...
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java/sql/SQLException
    at DatabaseKt.<clinit>(database.kt:6)
    at Data$transactions$2.invoke(Data.kt:17)
    at Data$transactions$2.invoke(Data.kt:15)
    at kotlin.SynchronizedLazyImpl.getValue(LazyJVM.kt:74)
    at Data.getTransactions(Data.kt:15)
    at ComposableSingletons$MainKt$lambda-1$1$1.invokeSuspend(Main.kt:37)
    at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(DispatchedTask.kt:106)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: java.sql.SQLException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 21 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: java.sql.SQLException
```

The database.tk where it fails only contains standard Ktorm db connection.

```
val database = Database.connect(
    url = dbUrl,
    user = dbUser,
    password = dbPw,
)
```

I tried creating an SQLException variable, with the same result

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: java.sql.SQLException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: java.sql.SQLException

    ... 43 more
Failed to launch JVM
```

Comment: how is the dependency on database driver defined in gradle build file?

Comment: implementation("org.ktorm:ktorm-core:3.4.1")
implementation("org.ktorm:ktorm-support-postgresql:3.4.1")
implementation("org.postgresql:postgresql:42.3.1")
implementation("me.liuwj.ktorm:ktorm-support-postgresql:3.1.0")